# How is the cockpit rear view of an Airbus A340?

Tags: airbus, cockpit

Before anything I know this can be sound something stupid and obvious, but I swear I lost 3 or 4 hours searching images and videos before posting this question. So please be mercy with my poor knowledge.

I'm looking for a view of the rear side of the cockpit (when the door is, and the third and four ocuppant seat is).

I only get a very partial views, and the more detailed image is a diagram from the cockpit deck layout (the following is an example from A330, I could get the A340, but I'm not looking for a diagram):

[image]

Everyone knows the typical eye-lens shot of the panel, but it was impressive to me that get one of the rear view is really difficult, more even after the tragedy of the Germanian, where a lot of shots has no relevance with I'm looking for.

Any help will be preciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I Googled for `a340 360 cockpit view` which returns, with others, [this result](http://www.airbus.com/fileadmin/backstage/files/virtual_visits/a340.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon, this really help me. I could not make a picture by the 360º but it's perfect for me, because I'm modeling the cockpit in scale. Thanks a lot! Could you make your comment as answer so I accept it? I think really answer this.

Comment: @Simon You need to put that as an answer so that Leandro can mark it as an accepted answer. I was about to put that Airbus link as the answer but then saw your comment.

Comment: It seems far too easy and small to post as an answer but I have done so.  I'm pleased that it helped you.

Comment: @Simon It's not about pleasing me, but rather doing the right thing. You gave a perfectly fine and correct answer, it should be posted as an answer not as a comment, regardless how *easy and small* it appears. Comments are for comments, not for answers. Oh, and thanks for doing that. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I Googled for "a340 360 cockpit view" that returns, with others, [this link](https://magazin.lufthansa.com/xx/en/fleet/airbus-a340-600-en/panorama-photo-cockpit-a340-600/).

The link is a 360-degree view of the A340 cockpit. Below is a frame grab for one of the angles:

[image]

Comment: the link does not work anymore